# How do I turn off the auto message on a new file in Webstorm IDE?

Tags: webstorm

When I create a new file in a webstorm project I get a superfluous message telling the next person 'who made the file and when'. Since the invention of source control I really don't see why jetBrains have decided to make this default anyway how do I turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you have `USER` and `DATE` as part of your file template:

[image]

Just get rid of the the stuff in the template and you should be good to go. In other words, get rid of 3 and 4, and you will no longer be prompted.

Usually webstorm will not prompt you for this, but for some reason in the installation the username was not added to its list of macros.